# Paperclip models not initialized properly - asset url pointing to filesystem instead of S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I have a strange issue. I just upgraded from 2.3.10 to rails 3.0.10 and using the latest Paperclip gem

The problem is, on Rails startup or in the console as well, it seems the storage S3 option is ignored.
I get the URL

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :006 > p.asset.url
"/system/assets/116/original/DSC07568.jpg?1270933446"
```

after I do a reload! in the console the url is the proper one

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :006 > reload!
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :006 > p = Photo.last
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :006 > p.asset.url
"http://development-assets0.domain.com/development/asse/116/original_DSC07568.jpg?1270933446"
```

my model declaration

```
 has_attached_file :asset,
  :styles => {
  :original => "1024x1024>",
  :medium => "267x267>",
  :thumb=> "100x100#",
  :small => "150x150>"
 },
 :storage => :s3,
 :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
 :bucket => BUCKET_NAME,
 :path => ":rails_env/asset/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
 #:url => ":rails_env/asset/:id/:style_:basename.:extension",
 :url => ':s3_alias_url',
 :default_url => "/images/processing.png",
 :processors => :thumbnail,
 :s3_host_alias => "#{Rails.env}-assets0.domain.com"
```

in the meantime I've tried to remove most of the other gems with no luck.

Comment: From the looks of your code your running a CDN setup. It seems strange to have the `:url` and `:s3_host_alias` options in the same config. Are these perhaps conflicting? Just posing the question, im not 100% sure on this.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem installing paperclip again as plugin and still requiring it in the Gemfile

```
rails plugin install https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
```

and adding it to the Gemfile

```
gem 'paperclip', :gem => https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git
```